# Opening an Iframe link in a new tab on the parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I have an iframe and the main window where the iframe is embedded. The iframe has a form where the user can input data and finally submit it.

Right now I use

```
var openURL = '/results/finalpage';
window.open(openURL, '_parent');
```

This opens the page result of iframe's form in the parent window and thereby the window which contained the iframe is now loaded with the new result page.

So I want to open results of the form in a new tab on the parent window. I am guessing we could use a href here to load in new tab. But the form submission has an `onclick` event which processes the input and changes the result page url accordingly. Is there any simple solution to do this?

Comment: Tabs aren't really something _you_ can control, it depends on how the browser is set up to handle new windows. And I'm guessing `_blank` won't work. Any way to do it without iframes?

Comment: Even if it could open it in a new window that should be fine. But it is being blocked by pop up blockers.

Answer (score -1):

_parent target is working correct, you need to select the top window and use _blank

```
var openURL = '/results/finalpage';
top.open(openURL, '_blank');
```

Comment: I tried this and it opens as a pop up which is being blocked by pop up blockers. Any idea how to open it as a new browser window instead of a pop up?

Comment: Popup blockers will typically only allow window.open if used during the processing of a user event.